# Swapping CUDA Thrust device vectors without memory movements

Tags: cuda, thrust

If I have two `cudaMalloc`ed arrays, I can swap them without memory movements by simply swapping the related pointers.

If I have two CUDA Thrust device_vectors, say `d_a` and `d_b`, I can swap them by using a third temorary vector, say `d_c`, but this will require memory movements.

My question is: is there a way to swap CUDA Thrust device_vectors without memory movements?

Comment: The `thrust::vector` class has a member of type `contiguous_storage` which  is used for storing the vector contents. When vectors are swapped, internally, only the `begin()` iterator, `size` and `allocator` of `contiguous_storage` are swapped. So there is no memory copy of data involved. You can check this in the [`swap`](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/thrust/detail/contiguous_storage.inl#L181) member function inside the file `contiguous_storage.inl`.

Comment: In the case of assignment operator, if you look at the code of [`vector_base::operator=`](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/thrust/detail/vector_base.inl#L89), it uses the `assign` function which seems to perform complete memory copy of the vector contents.

Comment: @sgarizvi Thanks for your comments. Actually, this is the same objection @talonmies pointed out in his comments below. However, the strange thing is that I cannot find memory copies in the timeline. Perhaps `thrust` uses a kernel to perform the copy?

Comment: @sgarizvi I have replaced the explicit copies with `swap` in my main code, with benefits on timing. At least, it seems that `swap` is faster than copy.

Comment: I think this is s relatively new feature of the vector classes. In the old days I'm pretty sure swap used copy assignment and that triggered memory copies.

Comment: I realize this is not directly the question you are asking, but couldn't you just use references to the vectors and swap those, wherever you need to?

Comment: @RobertCrovella Your comment perfectly fits the post. If you have an alternative solution using references to vectors, I believe that providing an answer with an example would be beneficial for the whole community. A question: is swapping references to vectors what is actually done by `device_vector.swap()` under the hood?

Comment: I had forgotten that references are not reseatable.  This can be done using pointers to vectors, but I think that is fairly obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that I am aware of.

There is no constructor exposed which takes an existing `device_ptr`, and the underlying base vector within `device_vector` is private, so there is no way to dive in and perform pointer exchange yourself. Those would be the only ways I can think of to make this work without triggering the standard copy constructor.

---

Edit to add that it appears this answer is wrong. It seems that recent (probably around thrust 1.6) changes have implemented an internal pointer exchange swap mechanism which can be called via `device_vector.swap()`. This bypasses the usual copy-constructor idiom for `swap()` and will not trigger memory transfers
.

Comment: If you are not aware of, then it is 99.99% likely that it is not possible :-) Thank you, as always.

Comment: Thinking about it, you might be able to do things by hacking a custom made allocator class which returns the memory of another device vector. But then you have lots of other problems which probably can't be solved

Comment: Just a question: does `d_b.swap(d_a)` implies memory movements?

Comment: I have used `d_b.swap(d_a)` and I see no device-to-device copy in the timeline (see edit).

Comment: It has been a while since I look at this, but I am 99% sure that all swaps in thrust use the copy constructor, and that triggers memory movements

Comment: I do not want to insist on this point (you are far more expert than me), but if I use `d_b.swap(d_a)`, then I do not see any device-to-device memory movement and if I use `d_b = d_a` I do (see the above timelines). How can I explain this?

Comment: I can't -- AFAIK this is `swap` https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/thrust/detail/swap.h  Just `temp=a; a=b; b=temp;`. That should cause memory movement

Comment: The timing appears to be significantly in favor of `d_b.swap(d_a)`, rather than `d_b = d_a`.

Comment: @JackOLantern: If you unaccept this answer I can delete it. You would be better to add your edit to the question as an answer and accept it. Mine is clearly not correct

Comment: I have unaccepted the answer, but probably it would be good not to delete it yet to avoid deleting the comments above. @sgarizvi tends also to the copy, as you objected. Perhaps `thrust` uses a kernel to perform the copy? In the meanwhile, I have removed the `copy` in my code and used `swap`, with benefits on timing.

Comment: I've edited the answer to reflect the newly (at least to you and I) behaviour of `device_vector.swap()`. If someone else wants to add a better answer I am still open to deleting this one

Comment: I have re-accepted your answer. I have also moved the edit to my post into another answer to clean up a bit the scenario.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that `device_vector.swap()` avoids memory movements.

Indeed, consider the following code:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>

#include <thrust\device_vector.h>

void printDeviceVector(thrust::device_vector<int> &d_a) {

    for (int k = 0; k < d_a.size(); k++) {

        int temp = d_a[k];
        printf("%i\n", temp);

    }

}

int main()
{
    const int N = 10;

    thrust::device_vector<int> d_a(N, 1);
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_b(N, 2);

    // --- Original
    printf("Original device vector d_a\n");
    printDeviceVector(d_a);
    printf("Original device vector d_b\n");
    printDeviceVector(d_b);

    d_b.swap(d_a);

    // --- Original
    printf("Final device vector d_a\n");
    printDeviceVector(d_a);
    printf("Final device vector d_b\n");
    printDeviceVector(d_b);

    d_a.clear();
    thrust::device_vector<int>().swap(d_a); 
    d_b.clear();
    thrust::device_vector<int>().swap(d_b);

    cudaDeviceReset();

    return 0;
}
```

using

```
    d_b.swap(d_a);
```

If we profile it, we see no device-to-device memory movement in the timeline:

[image]

If, on the other side, we change `d_b.swap(d_a)` to

```
d_b = d_a;
```

then device-to-device movements appear in the timeline:

[image]

Finally, the timing is significantly in favor of `d_b.swap(d_a)`, rather than `d_b = d_a`. For `N = 33554432`, the timing is

```
d_b.swap(d_a)     0.001152ms
d_b = d_a         3.181824ms
```